# Comparação entre objetos por meio de loop, If e else?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, mvc, objetos

Sou iniciante em java e estou com duvida na comparação objetos por meio de loop. Estou desenvolvendo um software para uma videolocadora com design pattern MVC(Model-view-controller) e quero saber como se compara o objeto pessoa por meio do código dele com o zero.
Quando faço esse loop, exibe a seguinte mensagem: Bad operand types for binary operator '>' .

```
 private boolean salvarPessoa(){
            OPDatas bl = new OPDatas();

            pessoa.setNome(this.txtNome.getText());
            pessoa.setBairro(this.txtBairro.getText());
            pessoa.setEndereco(this.txtEndereco.getText());
            pessoa.setCidade(this.txtCidade.getText());
            pessoa.setUf(this.txtUF.getText());
            pessoa.setCPF(this.txtCPF.getText());
            pessoa.setTelefone(this.txtTelefone.getText());
            pessoa.setdNascimento(bl.converterDataStringParaDate(this.txtdNascimento.getText()));// 



         // Esse é o loop e o objeto pessoa!
            if (pessoaController.salvar(pessoa> 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Registro gravado com sucesso!");
                this.desabilitarCampos();
                this.carregarClientes();
                return true;
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Erro ao gravar os dados!", "ERRO", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return false;
            }

         }
```

PessoaController:

```
public boolean salvar( String nome, String endereco, String bairro, String sexo, String telefone, String celular, String CPF, Date dNascimento, String cidade, String uf ) {

        boolean retorno;

        Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
        pessoa.setNome(nome);
        pessoa.setEndereco(endereco);
        pessoa.setBairro(bairro);
        pessoa.setSexo(sexo);
        pessoa.setTelefone(telefone);
        pessoa.setCelular(celular);
        pessoa.setCPF(CPF);
        pessoa.setdNascimento(dNascimento);
        pessoa.setCidade(cidade);
        pessoa.setUf(uf);


        retorno = pessoaDAO.salvar(pessoa);

        return retorno;
    }
```

Comment: Por que você está comparando se o objeto pessoa é maior que zero?

Comment: Para salvar a minha pessoa e se o codigo do objeto pessoa for maior que zero ele salva!

Comment: Pelo seu código o método salvar sempre retorna um booleano, com o retorno dele você sabe se a pessoa salvou ou não, veja minha resposta se te ajuda.

Comment: No pessoaController no metodo salvar a variavel booleana retorno não consta como inicializada!

Comment: Não tem sentido verificar o Id sendo que no método ele nem é usado (por causa dos parâmetros)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente, `if` e `else` **não são *loops***. Eles são operadores condicionais.

`for` e `while` fazem *loops*, ou seja, eles repetem uma mesma instrução **diversas** vezes até que determinada condição seja atendida. Diferente de `if` que faz uma instrução **se** determinada condição for atendida.

Agora, vamos ao que interessa. Você disse nos comentários

> Para salvar a minha pessoa e se o **codigo do objeto pessoa for maior que zero ele salva!**

Para verificar se o código é maior que zero e só depois salvar, você deve fazer

```
if (pessoa.getId() > 0) { //verifica se o ID é maior que zero
    if(pessoaController.salvar(pessoa)){ //instrução de salvar
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Registro gravado com sucesso!");
    }else{
        // Mensagem de erro
    }
}
```

Ai entramos em outro problema do seu código, o método `salvar()` em `PessoaController`. No código da questão o método está pedindo um monte de parâmetros, no caso, todos os atributos do objeto `Pessoa`.

```
public boolean salvar( String nome, String endereco, String bairro, String sexo, String telefone, String celular, String CPF, Date dNascimento, String cidade, String uf )
```

Porém, você está chamando o método `salvar()`, passando como parâmetro um objeto `Pessoa` e não passando todos os parâmetros que o método pede. **Isso gerará outro erro**.

A solução é mudar a assinatura do seu método `salvar()` para pedir como parâmetro um objeto `Pessoa`. Dessa forma, você pode popular os atributos do objeto e depois passar ele inteiro para o `PessoaController` salvar.

```
public boolean salvar(Pessoa pessoa) { ... }
```

Dessa forma, você pode usar a chamada do método como estás usando atualmente

```
pessoaController.savar(pessoa);
```

Comment: Muito boa a explicação e me ajudo bastante mas assim do jeito que voce falou não salva nada!

Comment: Jovem, o problema deve estar no seu método de `salvar()` em `pessoaDao` e isso é outra história. Se alguma das respostas aqui te ajudou no problema inicial marque-a como correta e abra uma nova pergunta com seu novo problema. @IgorContini

Comment: Está bem e vou fazer isso se encontra algum erro.

Answer (score 2):

Esse erro ocorre devido a esse trecho do seu código:

```
if (pessoaController.salvar(pessoa> 0)
```

Pois você está tentando verificar se um objeto é maior que um número.

Como você já tem o objeto Pessoa populado é desnecessário você passar todos os atributos nos parâmetros do método `salvar`, você pode passar o próprio objeto pessoa que já possui todos os atributos.

No PessoaController:

```
public boolean salvar(Pessoa pessoa) {
  boolean retorno;
  if(pessoa != null)
    retorno = pessoaDAO.salvar(pessoa);

  return retorno;
}
```

No seu método `salvarPessoa` você deve remover essa comparação de `pessoa > 0` e passar seu objeto pessoa como parâmetro do método. Como observado pelo @jbueno caso você precise verificar se existe um Id no objeto pessoa pra depois realizar o INSERT basta adicionar um if:

```
if (pessoa.getId() > 0 && pessoaController.salvar(pessoa)) {
 // restante do seu código
}
```

Caso possuir Id maior que zero e o método retorno for verdadeiro, ele salvou seu objeto. Lembrando que uma condição && só executa a segunda caso a primeira for atendida.

Comment: Muito boa a explicação e valeu ai!

Answer (score 1):

você nao consegue comparar se pessoa é maior que zero, porque ele é um objeto do tipo pessoa,

o que voce pode fazer é verificar o retorno do seu metodo salvar se é verdadeiro

```
// Esse é o loop e o objeto pessoa!
        if (pessoaController.salvar(pessoa)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Registro gravado com sucesso!");
            this.desabilitarCampos();
            this.carregarClientes();
            return true;
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Erro ao gravar os dados!", "ERRO", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Mudei a metodo salvar na pessoaController como o @jbueno pediu e e segui a sua dica na condiçao IF mas so salva o codigo da pessoa e não nome,cpf e etc..